# How can I open unlimited many pdf files (I have a strange limit of 15)

Tags: windows-10, pdf

When I mark more then about 15 pdf files (via ctrl + shift) I no longer get the options Open and Print. For less files it's Ok. How can I remove this limitation it? My default reader is Foxit.

Comment: This was a problem in w7 also, see if this solution works>>>>>https://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/05/fix-context-menu-items-missing-in-windows-explorer/

Comment: @Moab Will this work in Windows 10?

Comment: @OMGsh Try it and let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is select all the files you want to open with Shift/Ctrl, and then drag and drop them into the Foxit windows itself.